# php preg_match returns different result for same string

Tags: php, preg-match

I have a form and a tried to check the input value with preg_match. Here is the code:

`preg_match("/^\pL+(?>[- ']\pL+)*$/u",$county)`

It returns sometimes false for the string 'Miskolc'. But for others it returns true. And I don't know why. Maybe it depends on the user's browser?

Comment: no way that browser matters. Maybe some space or something is added in the form field?

Comment: @Tania I check for whitespaces before preg_match.

Comment: Is the string `Miskolc` or `'Miskolc'`?

Comment: How can we repro the issue? Note that it happens sometimes that there are unprintable chars at the stasrt/end of the string. Try to check with `"/^\W*\p{L}+(?>[- ']\p{L}+)*\W*$/u"`

Comment: @Toto the string is Miskolc.

Comment: So your regex should match. It works fine for me.